# Logical proposition statements with tautology symbol

Tags: logic

I am currently working on an assignment when I saw this come by:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HywS5.png)

I am uncertain on how I should interpret this statement. Should it be:
"a and b, a is a tautology" seen as a statement of "a and b" where a is always true or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually $\vDash$ means semantic entailment: if the stuff on the left is true, then the stuff on the right is true.

$\vDash a$ means $a$ is always true (as there is no "stuff on the left"), i.e., that $a$ is a tautology.

To check whether $a \land b \vDash a$ you need to check whether $a$ is true whenever $a\land b$ is true.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation! Hope I'll manage to get the correct conclusion :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret $\vDash$ as "logically entails".

So, $a \land b \vDash a$ means: "$a \land b$ logically entails $a$"

I am guessing that you will be able to use a truth-table to verify if that is indeed the case.